# Remove all the hash out value of teradata in unix

Tags: unix

Can anyone help me on this
I have one variable which contain

```
var="DDP_COMPLIANCE ,ONT_COMPLIANCE_CD --,TECHNICIAN_EMPLOYEE_ID --,ENTRY_OPERATOR_EMPLOYEE_ID --,LAST_UPDATE_OPERATOR_EMPLOYEE_ID ,PARENT_TROUBLE_CALL_WORK_ORDER_ID --,abc_line ,PARENT_INSTALL_WORK_ORDER_ID ,TECH_COMPLIANCE_STARTBY_TS "
```

i want to remove all the "--,columnname" and print rest

and the output will be

```
DDP_COMPLIANCE ,ONT_COMPLIANCE_CD,PARENT_TROUBLE_CALL_WORK_ORDER_ID ,PARENT_INSTALL_WORK_ORDER_ID ,TECH_COMPLIANCE_STARTBY_TS
```

i am using Sed command as

```
echo $var | sed 's/--.*,/,/'
```

but got output as

```
DDP_COMPLIANCE ,ONTRAC_COMPLIANCE_CD ,TECH_COMPLIANCE_STARTBY_TS
```

which is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a simple way, but for time being, this works for you?

```
echo $var | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' | grep -v "^--" | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; { print $0 }'
```

the last `awk` part was to format the result back in a single line.

Result:

```
$ echo $var | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' | grep -v "^--" | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; { print $0 }'
DDP_COMPLIANCE ,ONT_COMPLIANCE_CD ,PARENT_TROUBLE_CALL_WORK_ORDER_ID ,PARENT_INSTALL_WORK_ORDER_ID ,TECH_COMPLIANCE_STARTBY_TS
```